# Join two tables and display records only if 2nd table does not have a matching date

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables that I'm trying to join. I want to be able to join on ClientID, and only display those records where DateA does not match DateB. This is the structure of my tables

```
tbl1
CLientID             DateA
17                   08/01/2016
19                   06/27/2016
21                   12/1/2015


tbl2
RcrNo            ClientID           DateB
1                17                 08/01/2016
2                19                 06/27/2016
3                21                 12/22/2015
```

Desired Result:

```
ClientID             Date
21                   12/22/2015
```

SO as can be seen ClientID 21 is the only client out of the 3 whose DateA does not match DateB. How would I be able to join them like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `JOIN` and `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
       JOIN table2 ON table1.ClientId = table2.ClientId
WHERE  table1.date <> table2.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `except`:

```
select clientid, dateb
from tbl2
except
select clientid, datea
from tbl1;
```